# SBT hangs resolving dependencies

Tags: sbt

We have an SBT 0.13.0 multi-project build with 17 projects: 1 leaf project, 15 modules that depend on the leaf (but not each other), and 1 aggregator that depends on the 15 modules.

Here's a very rough idea of what the `Build.scala` file looks like:

```
val deps: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.foo" % "foo" % "1.0.0",
  "com.bar" % "bar" % "1.0.0"
))

val leaf = Project("leaf").settings(deps:_*)

val module1 = Project("module1").dependsOn(leaf).settings(deps:_*)
val module2 = Project("module2").dependsOn(leaf).settings(deps:_*)
...
val module15 = Project("module15").dependsOn(leaf).settings(deps:_*)

val aggregator = Project("aggregator)".dependsOn(
  module1,
  module2,
  ...
  module15
).settings(deps:_*)
```

All of these projects list *exactly* the same set of external dependencies as `libraryDependencies`. For some reason, when we run the `update` command in the aggregator, it takes on the order of a minute per project (~15 minutes total!), *even though there is no single new dependency to resolve or download*.

Worse yet, we recently added one more dependency and now the `update` command causes SBT to swell up to ~5GB of memory and sometimes hang completely during resolution. How do we debug this?

We tried YourKit to profile it and, it may be a read herring, but so far, the only thing we see is some `sbt.MultiLogger` class spending a ton of time in a `BufferedOutputStream.flush` call.

Comment: What is the SBT version ?

Comment: We're on SBT version 0.13.0

Comment: could you show the `build.sbt`s of the projects? maybe only the leaf, one module and the aggregator if module have the same configs..

Comment: @laughedelic: I added a rough idea of the build file.

Comment: do you use directly all these dependencies in the modules? if no, you can just leave `.dependsOn(leaf)` for them and in aggregator, maybe it's better to use `.aggregates(...)` instead of `.dependsOn`?

Answer (score 5):

If some of your external dependiencies are actually your own libraries pushed to a local repository and their version is set to "latest" then this hanging is expected. The reason is that ivy tries all repositories for all dependencies when "latest" version is required. Since your libraries are not pushed to public repositories then checking for them on public repositories ends in timeout (it is an ivy issue apparently).

I tried to replicate your setup and created an sbt project with leaf, 15 modules, aggregator and a few external dependencies. It all resolves quite quickly. You can check it out at

https://github.com/darkocerdic/sbt-multiproject-resolving